# Using Rx with, or alongside, Prism's EventAggregator - suggested approaches?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, system.reactive, eventaggregator

It strikes me that there is both some overlap and conflict between Prism's `EventAggregator` and Rx Framework, in that both are about subscribing to event streams. Rx obviously provides much more fine grained control, whilst the `EventAggregator` provides a loosely coupled, application wide, pub-sub infrastructure.

So my question is this, how can we effectively utilise both technologies together in the same application? Am I confusing their roles, or is there a distinction somewhere that I have missed? Does anyone have any experience of doing exactly this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an Rx friendly version of the same concepts as EventAggregator:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/MessageBus.cs

> Am I confusing their roles, or is there a distinction somewhere that I have missed?

Message Bus-type things are just one of the **many** ways you can use Rx in an application, the MVVM Framework I wrote called [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net) has many more ideas.

Comment: Not a bad implementation - one quibble, it's not a "drop-in" replacement for Prism's `EventAggregator` (i.e., needs wrapping)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to an Rx-based implementation of `EventAggregator`; like @paul-betts version in `ReactiveUI`, it's not a "drop-in" replacement, but also like his, it's easily wrapped.

[José F. Romaniello - Event Aggregator with Reactive Extensions](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/)